# Generating an XSLT file from XSD based upon a 1:1 mapping XSD compliant XML in -> XSD compliant XML out

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I know that the start of this question is contentious, so I hope that I've added enough clarifications, and that people read these.

I have a relatively complicated XSD file (well a set of XSD files, for each version of the schema).
What I'm ultimately looking for is a set of XSLT files which can take an XSD v12 compliant XML file, and transform it (throw away lots of stuff) until it becomes an XSD v3 compliant XML file.  It's possible that some of the transforms will be a little smarter, like taking a gradientStartColor and assigning that to backgroundFillColor if gradientMode="3"... but I'm not looking for this part to be done automatically.

So my Step 1 would be:
Generate an XSLT file which 'matches' an XSD file, such that a schema compliant XML file passes through untouched.  But where a schema non-compliant XML file has all those non-compliant attributes/elements stripped out.  I wouldn't even care about validation of values.

I would have expected there would be a way to auto-generate such an XSLT file.  But my googling has come up with no results.

I understand that XSLT isn't inherently schema aware (at least in XSLT 1), but I would expect that some automatic generation of an XSLT template could enumerate through the XSD to add in sufficient 'anchoring' that it emulates the schema.
Or am I misled on this thought?

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking to get work done or to undertake a research program?  If the former, roll up your sleeves and write the XSLT by hand (or hire an XSLT expert to do so); if the latter, and you're hoping for an easy *way to auto-generate such an XSLT file* then you've vastly underestimated the complexity.  Either way, you've got a lot more than a SO Q/A on your hands here.  Good luck, and if you make progress on a general solution, please get in touch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the solution was some .NET code.

```cs
using System;
using System.CodeDom;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using Microsoft.CSharp;

namespace Reverter
{
    class Program
    {
        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            //try
            {
                if (args.Length < 2)
                {
                    Console.Error.WriteLine("Reverter schema.xsd inputfile1 inputfile2...");
                    return 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    var schema = args[0];
                    List<string> srcFiles = new List<string>(args);
                    srcFiles.RemoveAt(0); // we get rid of the first entry, the schema


                    XmlSchemas xsds = new XmlSchemas();
                    XmlSchema xsd;
                    using (var r = File.OpenText(schema))
                    {
                        xsd = XmlSchema.Read(r, null);
                        xsds.Add(xsd);
                    }

                    xsds.Compile(null, true);

                    XmlSchemaImporter schemaImporter = new XmlSchemaImporter(xsds);

                    // create the codedom
                    CodeNamespace codeNamespace = new CodeNamespace("Schema");
                    XmlCodeExporter codeExporter = new XmlCodeExporter(codeNamespace);

                    List<XmlTypeMapping> maps = new List<XmlTypeMapping>();

                    foreach (XmlSchemaElement schemaElement in xsd.Elements.Values)
                    {
                        maps.Add(schemaImporter.ImportTypeMapping(schemaElement.QualifiedName));
                    }

                    foreach (XmlSchemaType schemaElement in xsd.Items.OfType<XmlSchemaType>())
                    {
                        maps.Add(schemaImporter.ImportSchemaType(schemaElement.QualifiedName));
                    }

                    foreach (XmlTypeMapping map in maps)
                    {
                        codeExporter.ExportTypeMapping(map);
                    }

                    codeNamespace.Types.OfType<CodeTypeDeclaration>().First(x => x.Name == "ROOTELEMENTNAME").Members.Add(
                        new CodeMemberProperty()
                        {
                            Name = "xsiSchemaLocation",
                            Attributes = MemberAttributes.Public | MemberAttributes.Final,
                            CustomAttributes =
                            {
                                new CodeAttributeDeclaration("System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute",
                                    new CodeAttributeArgument[]
                                    {
                                        new CodeAttributeArgument(new CodePrimitiveExpression("noNamespaceSchemaLocation")),
                                        new CodeAttributeArgument("Namespace", new CodePrimitiveExpression(XmlSchema.InstanceNamespace)),
                                    }
                                )
                            },
                            Type = new CodeTypeReference(typeof(string)),
                            HasGet = true,
                            GetStatements =
                            {
                                new CodeMethodReturnStatement(new CodePrimitiveExpression(schema))
                            },
                            HasSet = true,
                        });

                    // Check for invalid characters in identifiers
                    CodeGenerator.ValidateIdentifiers(codeNamespace);

                    CodeCompileUnit ccu = new CodeCompileUnit();
                    ccu.Namespaces.Add(codeNamespace);

                    CompilerParameters comParams = new CompilerParameters(
                        new string[] { "System.dll", "System.Xml.dll" } );
                    comParams.GenerateInMemory = true;
                    comParams.CompilerOptions = "/optimize";

                    CodeGeneratorOptions codeOptions = new CodeGeneratorOptions();
                    codeOptions.VerbatimOrder = true;

                    TextWriter memText = new StringWriter();

                    // output the C# code
                    CodeDomProvider codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
                    var codeResult = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromDom(comParams, new CodeCompileUnit[] { ccu });

                    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(codeResult.CompiledAssembly.GetType("Schema.ROOTELEMENTTYPE", true, true));
                    Object obj;

                    XmlWriterSettings xmlSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
                    xmlSettings.Indent = true;
                    xmlSettings.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                    xmlSettings.OmitXmlDeclaration = false;


                    foreach (string srcFile in srcFiles)
                    {
                        var dstFile = "New" + srcFile;
                        // using our XmlSerializer, we will load and then save the XMLfile
                        using (var file = new XmlTextReader(srcFile))
                        using(var outFile = XmlWriter.Create(dstFile, xmlSettings))
                        {
                            obj = ser.Deserialize(file);
                            ser.Serialize(outFile, obj);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            /*catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine("Revert code generation failed.");
                Console.Error.Write(ex.ToString());
                return 2;
            }*/

            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Pretty much just take the XSD file as input to the CodeDom engine, generate a compiled assembly, grab the root type from the new assembly, then deserialize and re-serialise the objects.  If you want some console printing for what was thrown away then you can generate callbacks for the UnknownElement, UnknownAttribute or UnknownNode events on the XmlDeserializer.

Answer (score 0):

It's a pretty tough thing to attempt and it doesn't surprise me that no-one has done it. People have written PhD theses on small parts of the problem, for example taking two grammars (content models) and working out if one is a subset of the other.

And clearly there are mappings that you cannot automate: whereas deleting elements that are no longer permitted is easy enough, adding elements that have become mandatory, or renaming those whose name has changed, or updating those whose type has changed, is going to be rather harder.

If you restrict your ambitions to a few simple cases, you might be able to make progress. But I would focus on making it useful for your particular use case, rather than making it general-purpose.

Comment: I guess I was expecting there might be something out there that would generate pretty much an xsl:template for each xsd complex type, with appropriate mappings for each attribute, and applying templates for each child element...  

I guess it'll be easier to just convert the XML schema into an XmlSerializer class structure on the fly (using CodeDom), compile it into an assembly, deserialize to the XSD generated classes, and then reserialize it back to a new XML file.  

It feels that XSLT should have made it easier.

Comment: It's always nice if someone before you has written exactly the program you need, but sadly it doesn't always happen.